# How to retrieve data in put_file_contents in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I am having a trouble with my code. My goal is to write a data in txt file and retrieve that data.
In writing data I used an array. And I added the FILE_APPEND parameter for rewriting the text file.
After I write the data into the text file I serialize it first. Then after writing the data I retrieve it using file_get_contents. I unserialize this also to display in array form.

Now my problem is. If I add new data the textfile will be overwrite but in displaying my data into array. It will always get the first index the index '0'. I can't get all the serialized array.

Here's my code:

```
$data_add = array(

                array(
                    'restaurant_id' => $restaurant_id,
                    'new_lat' => $new_lat_entry,
                    'new_long' => $new_long_entry,
                    'date_updated' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                )

            );


            $serialize_data = serialize($data_add);
            file_put_contents("test.txt", $serialize_data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX); //write the text file

...

$array = unserialize(file_get_contents('test.txt'));

print_r($array); //display it
```

My sample .txt file

```
a:1:{i:0;a:4:{s:13:"restaurant_id";s:4:"1212";s:7:"new_lat";s:8:"14.69327";s:8:"new_long";s:9:"120.96785";s:12:"date_updated";s:19:"2013-11-14 08:34:50";}}
a:1:{i:0;a:4:{s:13:"restaurant_id";s:4:"1229";s:7:"new_lat";s:8:"14.61431";s:8:"new_long";s:9:"120.99054";s:12:"date_updated";s:19:"2013-11-14 08:35:10";}}
```

But what I got in the array is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [restaurant_id] => 1212
            [new_lat] => 14.69327
            [new_long] => 120.96785
            [date_updated] => 2013-11-14 08:34:50
        )

)
```

How can I retrieve all the values from my array?

Comment: You got out what you thew in. Sounds like "working as intended" to me. WHat did you expect to get out instead?

Comment: As you can see in my sample txt file I have 2 data. But when I display in the array it will get the first one. The array couldn't get the whole data. I can't spot where my code goes wrong. I guess it is in the array.

Comment: I can see that NOW ^^ I'm pretty sure that wasn't in there when I wrote that comment :D (Oh. Ok. It was. But You had to scroll and read the entire serialized string to notice it... way better now ^^)

Comment: So what should I do to append my new data into the existing? Should I replace the index to an associative index?

Comment: See @CrayonViolet's answer. There is pretty much everything covered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

appending another serialized string isn't going to make `unserialize` magically read the entire thing as a single serialized variable.  You need to change your code to first get the current contents and unserialize it, then merge your current array with the previous data, then serialize it and put it back.

Alternatively you can put them on separate lines and then read and unserialize each line and merge then.

**edit:** example. This works, but ideally you should check the structure of the unserialized data to make sure it's shiny before attempting to add to it.

```
$data_add =  array(
  'restaurant_id' => $restaurant_id,
  'new_lat' => $new_lat_entry,
  'new_long' => $new_long_entry,
  'date_updated' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
);

$data = unserialize(file_get_contents('test.txt'));
$data[] = $data_add;

$serialize_data = serialize($data);
file_put_contents("test.txt", $serialize_data, LOCK_EX); //write the text file

$array = unserialize(file_get_contents('test.txt'));

echo "<pre>";
print_r($array); //display it
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to first read out the contents, unserialise it, add you content to the values, then write the whole array back out.